# why will this date compare not work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

So i have a small prob..

if i put in js like below :

```
 var date1 = '05/05/2012'

 var date2 = 06/06/2014'

if (date2 > date1){

alert('it works');
}
```

But  this does not seem to work? i mean it does not alert ..why?

But the date2 i am actually using like below :

```
date2 = document.getElementById(date_id).value; // '06/06/2014'
```

i echoed or alert the date2 to the browser and its perfeclty displaying as '06/06/2014' ..

But the condition does not work? any clues

Comment: That is a string, not a date object. Also, you are missing a ' in date2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing string objects not dates.

Use a Date() Object

```
 var date1 = new Date('05/05/2012');

 var date2 = new Date('06/06/2014');
```

Comment: It would however be safest to use the ISO format:  YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

Comment: Very true, I moved when I was young so I learned both M/D/Y AND D/M/Y and to this day I still get confused unless I put it in ISO.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
var date1 = new Date(year1, month1, day1);
var date2 = new Date(year2, month2, day2);

// compare it
date1 < date2 && console.log('date1 < date2');
date1 > date2 && console.log('date1 > date2');
date1.getTime() == date2.getTime() && console.log('date1 == date2');
```